# How to decompile html, css, js code in to html

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, decompiling

I have a problem, I wanted to edit ui but the problem is that all the code is in the 1 line and I can't find a way to decompile the code to normal state. Can anyone help?

```
<html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css"><title>BroPixel Phone</title><link rel="preload" href="bankgothic.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin/><link rel="preload" href="pdown.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin/><style>@font-face{font-family:bankgothic;src:url(bankgothic.ttf);font-display:swap}@font-face{font-family:Pricedown;src:url(pdown.ttf);font-display:swap}</style><link href="2.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="main.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><div id="hud"></div><div id="root" style="height:100%;position:relative;overflow:hidden"></div><script src="bundle.js"></script><script src="2.chunk.js"></script><script src="main.chunk.js"></script></body></html>
```

Comment: Search the web for 'unminify HTML'

Answer (score 2):

You can use online beautifiers. VS Code can also help you with its beautifiers or via supported extensions such as prettier.

https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer

Comment: You can check the ui here. https://github.com/jekabso21/pixel-admin/tree/main/ethicalpixel-adminmenu/ui-build

I have the problem that the chunk codes are not complete and there are things missing I think.

Comment: Usually there would be src (source) folder and you develop UI in src. Then with module bundlers (for this case webpack) you extract src folder into another folder (build for this case). Build process shortened files and usually encode them. I would not try to decompile build folder if not necessary. Maybe ask for src file but ı guess it is intentionally not there. If you still want to go that direction there are online js, css, json beautifiers also.